# GWT AJAX no browser mouse loading

Tags: ajax, gwt, browser, jersey-1.0

I'm using GWT, and I run a scheduled (with Timer) background task that fetches some info from the server every 10 seconds.

My problem is that every call is an AJAX call (using Jersey) and the browsers (most of them) show a loading image next to the mouse cursor while the request is processing. The request is very fast but the loading image appearing for a few millis is very anoying.

Any idea how to disable the loading image on this specific AJAX Jersey call ?

Thanks,
Max.

Answer (score 0):

Loading icon has nothing to do with GWT. It will be usually a .gif handled via CSS. Point out where the particular css class is getting added and handle accordingly